# Join 2 echoes and separate with coma - implode, array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, implode

I've got 2 variables. First is coming from the taxonomy and outputs the taxonomy  term and the second outputs the custom field:

```
$address_city = get_custom_field( 'address_city' );
        echo '<span>' . $address_city . '</span>';

$terms = get_the_terms($post->id, 'listing_country');
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '<span>' . $term->name . '</span>';
}
```

The result of this looks like this: ***CityCountry***

I'm trying to figure out how to separate these two echos with a single coma `,`, so the result is as follows: ***City, Country***

I've been trying to play around with the `implode()` and `array()` , but I just can't figure out how to get this done without errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$address_city = get_custom_field( 'address_city' );
        $arr[0] = '<span>' . $address_city . '</span>';

$terms = get_the_terms($post->id, 'listing_country');
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $arr[1] = '<span>' . $term->name . '</span>';
}    
    echo implode(", ", $arr);
```

try this code it will help you for sure..

Comment: Thanks Pravin .. how do I wrap your code with the echoes? What would the final code look like?

Comment: is it necessary to echo in span?

Comment: if it's not then instead of echo store those values in array variable

Comment: I see, that works perfectly .. thanks for your help!

Comment: Quick question, at the moment, I'm not getting the space between the terms, so I get the coma, but it looks like this: City,Country.

How do I get the space behind the coma, so it looks like: City, Country ??

Comment: just add space in implode function after , like this implode(", ", $arr);

Comment: the span was actually causing the issue for some reason, so removed the span and put those values into array variable just like in your very first answer and now all works good.